# navigate to one screen tp another

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating react native application in this application i wanted to navigate one child view to another child view. Here i have list of applieduser which contains details of the user who have applied for the project.On click of that list item i will be able to view his/her profile
What i have done :

```
 onUserClicked() {
    //Fetch Applied User And Show to screen
    console.log(this.props.data.uid);
    NavigationService.navigate('ViewActorProfileScreen', { id: this.props.data.uid });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onUserClicked.bind(this)} >
        <CardSection style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{this.props.data.category}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>
              Gender - {this.props.data.gender}
            </Text>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Email - {this.props.data.email}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Address - {this.props.data.address}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Language : {this.props.data.language}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Number - {this.props.data.mobile}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>{this.props.data.description}</Text>
          <IconButton
            onPress={this.onChatClicked.bind(this)}
            iconname="comment"
            lable="chat"
          />
        </CardSection>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

NavigationService :

```
    import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params
    })
  );
}

export default { setTopLevelNavigator, navigate };
```

rootStack.js

```
    const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
{
  HomeScreen: Home,
  Login: LoginScreen,
  SignUpScreen: UserSignUp,
  ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen,
  updateProfile: UserProfileScreen,
  viewActorProfile:ViewActorProfileScreen
},
{
   initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen'
}
);
```

Index.js

```
    export * from './UpdateActorProfile';
export * from './ViewProject';
export * from './ViewActorProfileScreen';
export * from './AppliedProjectUsers';
export * from './AppliedUserList';
```

i have created viewAcotrProfileScreen page which will contain UI for viewing the profile and i have also add that file into component/index.js file.but i m not able to navigate to the page. i m newbie for the react native please draw me to the problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show code of `NavigationService` and your root navigation

Comment: @SGhaleb there is no issue with the navigation services cause i m able to navigate on anoher page/ but here i cant. though i have updated the code. please check and let me know

Comment: Do you get any errors when you click `onUserClicked()`. Also does this `console.log(this.props.data.uid);` show up on console?

Comment: nope it shows uid

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong on these code snippets. What about `ViewActorProfileScreen` component AND the root page where you define the navigation

Comment: Code updated @SGhaleb

Comment: I think it's because you need to pass `viewActorProfile` in your `onPress() `. As this `ViewActorProfileScreen` is actual page, not route name in navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the navigation name to...

`NavigationService.navigate('viewActorProfile', { id: this.props.data.uid }); }`

Also, your MainStack is very inconsistent and will confuse you to make further mistakes like this.

`HomeScreen: Home, Login: LoginScreen, SignUpScreen: UserSignUp, ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen, updateProfile: UserProfileScreen, viewActorProfile:ViewActorProfileScreen`

For better organisation ensure one side ends with `Screen` not mix it up